# Why is Hadoop MapReduce so slow and not using all of the available resources?

Tags: performance, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently testing the performance of Apache Hadoop in a 9 node cluster with each node having 4Gig RAM plus 2 CPU's and determined that when submitting a single job the resources of the cluster (RAM, CPU, NET, disk I/O) are nearly unused.

What are the limited factors that prevent MapReduce to use all available resources?

Comment: What does your job do, how is your cluster configured, what's you input data set size, ..., ..., ...., My guess is your job is the limiting factor. Have you tried the benchmarking jobs like TeraSort?

Comment: I am using Hive HBase Mappings and tried different queries: SELECT * FROM ORDER BY, SELECT count(*) GROUP BY, ... It only uses about 5% of the available resources which I think is very low.

Comment: There are hundreds of things that could be affecting this. Does it use all mappers? Is it IO bound in any way?

Comment: Yes all mappers. Very few I/O throughput.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confusion over hadoop job tracker api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264099/confusion-over-hadoop-job-tracker-api)