# Confusion over hadoop job tracker api

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, jobs

I'm try to collect some information from the job tracker. For starters I'd like to start with getting running jobs info such as job id or job name etc. But already stuck, here is what I've got (prints out job ids for currently running jobs):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "zk1.myhost,zk2.myhost,zk3.myhost");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

        InetSocketAddress jobtracker = new InetSocketAddress("jobtracker.mapredhost.myhost", 8021);
        JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobtracker, conf);
        JobStatus[] jobs = jobClient.jobsToComplete();

        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
            JobStatus js = jobs[i];
            if (js.getRunState() == JobStatus.RUNNING) {
                JobID jobId = js.getJobID();
                System.out.println(jobId);
            }
        }
    }
```

This **above** works as charm when trying to display job id, but now I want to display the job name as well. So I added this line after printing job id :

```
System.out.println(jobClient.getJob(jobId).getJobName());
```

I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$NetworkedJob.<init>(JobClient.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJob(JobClient.java:1080)
    at org.apache.test.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:28)
```

`jobClient` is not `null`. I know this because I tried with null check if statement, but this `jobClient.getJob(jobId)` is `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

According to the API I should be ok,

http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getJob(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID)

First get `RunningJob` from jobClient than once you have running job then get it's name http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/RunningJob.html#getJobName()

Anyone did something like this before? I could use [jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsoup) to obtain this information trough GET request but I think this is better way to get this information.

Question update here is my hadoop/hbase dependencies :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.1-mr1-cdh4.0.0b2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.1-mr1-cdh4.0.0b2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.92.1-cdh4b2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Bounty update :**

Here are my imports :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobStatus;
```

Here is the output of `System.out.println(jobId)` :

```
job_201207031810_1603
```

There is only one job currently running.

Comment: What version are you using? 0.21 like in your doc links?

Comment: hi Thomas that is good observation I'll update my question

Comment: So your cluster runs on 0.23.1 from CDH4 like your dependencies?

Comment: that's correct. As I mentioned in the question, I have no issues with getting the job ids of running jobs. But getting their name is the issue

Comment: please include the imports from the top of the file containing the main method.

Comment: Also please include the actual output from the call to `System.out.println(jobId);`.

Comment: Is it possible that the job finished after you got the id, but before you got its name?  It seems like that might be a real world condition you have to watch out for.

Comment: Yes it is possible of course, but this one has been running for 18hrs already and it's just 50 % trough map part so in this case no.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at the inner class `NetworkedJob` of `JobClient`. 
 
(source: /home/user/hadoop/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.java)

Its constructor tries to fetch the `Configuration` object from `JobClient` in line 225 but it's null since `new JobClient(InetSocketAddress jobTrackAddr, Configuration conf)` doesn't set it:

```
// Set the completion poll interval from the configuration.
      // Default is 5 seconds.
      Configuration conf = JobClient.this.getConf();
      this.completionPollIntervalMillis = conf.getInt(COMPLETION_POLL_INTERVAL_KEY,
          DEFAULT_COMPLETION_POLL_INTERVAL); //NPE occurs here!
```

As a workaround, set it manually after creating the JobClient object. This will solve your problem:

```
..
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(jobtracker, conf);
jobClient.setConf(conf); 
....
```

Sidenote:

I instantiated the `Configuration` object via:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/path_to/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/path_to/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Comment: Excellent observation Sir! works if you manually setConf to jobClient, can't assign bounty yet

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow you can award the bounty at any time by clicking the little +250 button next to Lorand's answer